# Implement press="c.someMethod" on a custom component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom-button, lightning, event

I'm building a generic button lightning component, and I don't find how to implement a parameter which will trigger a controller JS function on the component including the button ( exactly like the press parameter of ui:button )

Sample:

```
CmpButton.cmp
    <aura:attribute name="press" type="????">
    <ui:button press="???" />

SomeComponent.cmp
    <c:CmpButton press="{c.someComponentMethod}" />

SomeComponent.js
    someComponentMethod: function(component,event,helper){
       // action on SomeComponent
}
```

I would like SomeComponent.someComponentMethod to be called when my included button is pressed

Many thanks & best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the attribute of type `AuraAction`. This will enable you to pass in the handler action directly.

Define it like this:

```
<aura:attribute name="press" type="Aura.Action" default="{!c.someAction}"/>
```

Your button would use it like this:

```
<button class="some class"  onclick="{!v.press}" >press me!</button>
```

The parent component would use it like this:

```
<c:CmpButton press="{!c.someComponentMethod}"/>
```

Comment: Aura.Action is not very well documented eh

Comment: Seems not at all according to Google ... Let's hope they won't disable it with LockerService ...

https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=salesforce+lightning+Aura.action